# SQL Query to pull the avg values for 1day gap dob's of clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a requirement with a below table.

conditions:-
1>   i have to take the avg of salaries clints, who has 1day date of birth gap.
2>   if there are no nearest 1day dob's gap between the gap between the clients, then no need to take that client into consideration.

please see the results.

Table:

```
ClientID    ClinetDOB's         Slaries
1           2012-03-14              300  
2           2012-04-11              400  
3           2012-05-09              200  
4           2012-06-06              400  
5           2012-07-30              600  
6           2012-08-14              1200  
7           2012-08-15              1800  
8           2012-08-17              1200  
9           2012-08-20              2400  
10          2012-08-21              1500
```

Result Should looks LIKE this:-

```
ClientID    ClinetDOB's         AVG(Slaries)
7           2012-08-15              1500        --This avg of 1200,1800(because clientID's 6,7 have dob's have 1day gap)    
10          2012-08-20              1950        --This avg of 2400,1500(because clientID's 9,10 have dob's have 1day gap))
```

Please help.

Thank You In advance!

Comment: Why avg for ClientID = 10 is not 1950?

Comment: Nikola, Wrong digits entered, Please find the updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A self-join will connect current record with all records having yesterday's date. In this context group by allows many records having the same date to be counted. `t1` needs to be accounted for separately, so the Salary is added afterwards, and count(*) is incremented to calculate average.

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26fab/5).

```
select t1.ClientID, 
       t1.ClinetDOBs,
       (t1.Slaries + sum (t2.Slaries)) / (count (*) + 1) Avg_Slaries
  from table1 t1
 inner join table1 t2
    on t1.ClinetDOBs = dateadd(day, 1, t2.ClinetDOBs)
 group by t1.ClientID, 
       t1.ClinetDOBs,
       t1.Slaries
```

Comment: Thank You The SQL Expert! Working.