# SQL query to find the avg salary based on the nearest client dob's

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement with a below table.

Conditions:

1. I have to take the average of salaries clients, if the client has serial 3 days date of birth gap.
2. If there are no nearest 3 day dob's gap between the gap between the clients, then no need to take that client into consideration.

Example:
in the below table
client 17 has previous clientid's WITH serial dob's with 1day gap -> in this case I'll TAKE salary AVG FOR 17 BY taking 15,16 & 17 salaries.
                    client 18 has previous clientid's WITH serial dob's -> in this case I'll TAKE salary AVG FOR 18 BY taking 16,17 & 18 salaries.

Table:

```
JobType    ClientID     ClinetDOB's         Slaries
.net        1           2012-03-14              300  
.net        2           2012-04-11              400  
.net        3           2012-04-12              200  
.net        4           2012-07-29              400

.net        5           2012-08-17              1200 
.net        6           2012-08-18              1400 
.net        7           2012-08-19              1400

java        8           2012-04-10              400
java        9           2012-07-29              400  
java        10          2012-07-30              600  

java        11          2012-08-14              1200  
java        12          2012-08-15              1800  
java        13          2012-08-16              1100

java        14          2012-09-17              1200 

java        15          2012-08-18              2400 
java        16          2012-08-19              2400  
java        17          2012-08-20              2400  
java        18          2012-08-21              1500
```

Result Should looks LIKE this:-

```
 JobType   ClientID     ClinetDOB's         AVG(Slaries)
.net        7           2012-08-19              1333
Java        13          2012-08-16              1366        --This avg of 5,6,7 clientsId's(because they have serial 3days dob's)    
Java        17          2012-08-20              2400        --This avg of 15,16,17 clientsId's(because they have serial 3days dob's)
Java        18          2012-08-21              2100        --This avg of 16,17,18 clientsId's(because they have serial 3days dob's)
```

Below query giving the some messup results.

```
select t1.ClientID,  
       t1.ClinetDOBs, 
       (t1.Slaries + sum (t2.Slaries)) / (count (*) + 1) Avg_Slaries 
  from table1 t1 
 inner join table1 t2 
    on (t1.ClinetDOBs = dateadd(day, 3, t2.ClinetDOBs) and t1.jobtype = t2.jobtype) 
 group by t1.ClientID,  
       t1.ClinetDOBs, 
       t1.Slaries
```

Please help.

Thank You In advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this - difference is that from t2 are taken rows from previous three days, which include current row being tested so no double-summing is needed. Also ˙having` removes rows that reference themselves only.

```
select t1.ClientID, 
       t1.ClinetDOBs,
       avg(t2.Slaries) Avg_Slaries
  from table1 t1
 inner join table1 t2
    on t1.ClinetDOBs >= t2.ClinetDOBs
   and t1.ClinetDOBs <= dateadd(day, 3, t2.ClinetDOBs)
   and t1.jobtype = t2.jobtype 
 group by t1.ClientID, 
       t1.ClinetDOBs
having count(*) > 1
```

[You can see it on your last data here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26fab/23).

Answer (score 2):

The following query joins in each of the three preceding records.  The joins both bring in the data and act as a filter to ensure that there are three:

```
select tmain.ClientID, tmain.ClinetDOBs,
       sum(tmain.slaries + t1.slaries + t2.slaries)/3.0 as avg_slaries
from table1 tmain join
     table1 t1
     on t1.ClinetDOBs = dateadd(day, -1, tmain.ClinetDOBs) and 
        t1.jobtype = tmain.jobtype join
     table t2
     on t2.ClinetDOBs = dateadd(day, -2, tmain.ClinetDOBs) and 
        t2.jobtype = tmain.jobtype
group by tmain.ClientID, tmain.ClinetDOBs, tmain.Slaries
```

You question seems odd.  Why do the dates have to be sequential and why do they all have to be there?  What happens if there are multiple people on the same date and job title?

Comment: The dates should be sequential as per my project business logic. At my project there is no case of happening to multiple people with same dates and same jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select t1.ClientID,  
       t1.ClinetDOBs, 
       avg(t2.Slaries)
  from table1 t1 
 inner join table1 t2 
    on t2.ClinetDOBs >= t1.ClinetDOBs) 
       t2.ClinetDOBs <= dateadd(day, 3, t1.ClinetDOBs)
       and t1.jobtype = t2.jobtype 
 group by t1.ClientID,  
       t1.ClinetDOBs
```

Comment: If I see one line missing from an answer I will comment rather than copy paste.

Comment: [Original query was mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075083/sql-query-to-pull-the-avg-values-for-1day-gap-dobs-of-clients/12075925#12075925). Your rework did not even compile. Then I decided to do it myself, and came to solution _not using yours_. See the aliases in join clause.